# Fortnite Tracker API seems not to be working or I am doing something wrong?

Tags: java, android, api

I have run into one problem. I want to get data from fortnite tracker [API](https://fortnitetracker.com/site-api), I have my own API key from the site and I am quite sure that I am doing everything fine but the site returns me `ErrorInputStream` with this message:

```
{"message":"Invalid authentication credentials"}
```

I am **100%** sure that I am giving right credintials to the site.

```
private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private EditText editText;

private static String APIKEY = "some-api-key";
private static String REQUEST_URL = "https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/%platform%/%epic-nickname%";
private static String LOG_TAG = "INFO";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
}

public void searchStats(View view) {
    if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a nickname !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        editText.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select a platform !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        radioGroup.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    DownloadTask dt = new DownloadTask();
    dt.execute();
}

private String getSelectedPlatformName(RadioGroup group) {
    RadioButton button =  findViewById(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    return button.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
}

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(REQUEST_URL.replaceAll("%platform%", getSelectedPlatformName(radioGroup)).replaceAll("%epic-nickname%", editText.getText().toString()));
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestProperty("TRN-Api-Key", "some-api-key");
            InputStream inputStream;
            int responseStatusCode = con.getResponseCode();
            if( responseStatusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ) {
                inputStream = con.getErrorStream();
            } else {
                inputStream = con.getInputStream();
            }
            String data = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, con.getContentEncoding());
            System.out.println(data);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "done";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: con.setRequestProperty("TRN-Api-Key", "some-api-key");. Are you sure that you are passing the correct api key and the correct "key" (TRN-Api-Key)? I mean the error is very clear: Invalid authentication credentials

Comment: Yes I am sure..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an User-Agent before you set the TRN-Api-Key!

> con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");